# Writing to a 'Middle-Man' kind of file before writing to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm currently coding in C# WinForms on Visual Studio 2008, and we might be implementing SQL database connectivity. However, it has to be very robust for industrial work, meaning the potential for power outages during the writing process.

I was thinking of making a file in between the app and SQL. The program first flips a SAFE flag on the file set to FALSE, then writes to it. Once it has been safely written to that file, it flips the SAFE flag to TRUE, THEN writes it to the SQL database. Is such a thing possible/the best course of action for outage prone environments?

Comment: How about when there is a power outtake during writing to the database?

Comment: What's the advantage of using a staging file over simply using the built-in transactions of your SQL database?

Comment: Why not just do it in a transaction? If it fails, nothing gets committed?

Comment: My knowledge of SQL is a little rudamentary. Sorry for the newbie question here. Transactions in SQL can help when it comes to power outages then? It's also important that no information is lost at all, such as customer sale data. Stuff like that can't be lost due to an outage, for instance.

Comment: Seems to me that your architecture is missing a tier. Are the clients really hooking straight up to the DB?

Comment: Sh*t happens. You can't ever expect all data to be retained throughout the system through unexpected power cycles. It's better to detect failure and react in a way that retains integrity at both client and server.

Comment: @user3215251 A transaction will make sure ALL the information for the transaction was written to the DB. So if the power goes down mid-write, when it comes back up, it will "roll back" what it has done, and you can have it try to write it again, guaranteeing success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to implement transactions.

If the power goes out , you can set your transaction to hold over to attempt to re-write the information when the system comes back online.

Answer (score 0):

i think that a sql write inside a transaction (begin...commit) is way more robust than anything you can implement as a single developer.
if you get a positive ack from the server that the data has been written then you can be sure it has.
if not then you know that you have to retry.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to your database you can use various technologies including a Message Queue to ensure the message is delivered to its destination, transaction processing to ensure that the whole save is completed or aborted. If you use SQL server it will also manage transactions that have not been saved to the database in the Transaction log thereby solving the problem of recovery after an outage. You therefore need to look at a couple of technologies:

Message Queuing : [Microsoft Message Queue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732184.aspx)

Transaction Processing : [Transaction Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee818756%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Transaction Logs : [SQL Server Transaction Logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190925.aspx)

Comment: And of course you buy a battery backup for your server(s).